# Higher roots modulo prime complexity best algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, computer-algebra

Given integers $a,\ell$ and prime $p$ we need to find the roots of the algebraic equation $x^\ell\equiv a\bmod p$. We know there are at most $\ell$ such $x$.

1. What is the best method to find all such $x$?
2. What is the complexity (is it $O(poly(\ell\log p)$?)?

Comment: There are *randomized* polynomial-time algorithms for factoring of polynomials over finite fields, your problem is a special case of that. Efficient *deterministic* algorithms are an open problem already for square root computation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek saying efficient deterministic square root calculations mod $p$ are "an open problem" and nothing more about them is not telling the whole story, since it might suggest there is no idea what such an algorithm might look like.  The paper of Adleman, Manders, and Miller at https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf provides such an algorithm (for square roots) under GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions.

Comment: Polynomial time polynomial factoring gives polynomial time in $\ell$ - not in $log(\ell)$ - which is not polynomial time in the input length.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser This depends on whether you write $\ell$ in unary or in binary, but in any case, polynomial in $\ell$ is exactly what the OP asks for.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek True that. I think the OP is asking what the best method is, and whether the complexity is a particular one. But maybe I misunderstood your comment: are randomized polynomial factoring algorithms, that take $poly(\ell log(p))$ time, the best known? With no dependence on $\ell$?

Comment: I don’t know if there are better randomized algorithms known for the specific case of $\ell$-th roots. (Certainly various steps in the generic factoring algorithms can be simplified, but an altogether different method would be needed to get a superpolynomial speedup.)

Answer (score -1):

This is essentially the same question as that of finding primitive roots mod $p,$ and this is discussed at length in [Ofer Grossman's nice report (2015).](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2015/207/)

Comment: Where can one read on the hinted equivalence of the two problems? Are they polynomialy reducible to each other?